# How to guarantee space for an ImageView, keep it from shrinking?

Tags: android, android-layout, width, android-imageview

I need to create an XML with the following content:
* Two TextViews with varying text (1- 3 rows), one TextView below the other.
* One ImageView to the right of the 2 TextViews, centered vertically, 30x30 px.

One major **limitation** is that it can't take the whole screen when inflated into a PopupWindow, which means that I cannot use the attributes fill_parent in many places.

I tried a lot of different layouts, but the ImageView keeps getting pushed away by the TextViews when the text is long. When the text is "half long" the image gets tiny but is still visible. I want it to always be 30x30 px, the text can wrap and use another line instead.

I tried to specify values for width and minWidth. Also tried layout_weight="1" for the ImageView. Also tried wrapping the ImageView into a LinearLayout and give that the layout_weight="1" parameter. Nothing works.

Here's an example of what is not working:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView android:id="@+id/popupTitle" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       <TextView android:id="@+id/popupContent"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/img_30x30_px" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You might have better luck with a RelativeLayout

Comment: Whats the maximum width and height the ImageView may take? It'd be of help if you could mock-up the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem and i found that the TableView layout worked for me. It took a while but you can play with the stretch and strink columns proeprties to change the behaviour of how the columns expand to match there content.

Note that you should be able to set the linearLayout of your text to fill_parent (to fill the column space).

Read this on how TableRow works http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

```
<TableRow>
    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Open..."
                android:padding="3dip" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Ctrl-O"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="3dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/img_30x30_px" />
</TableRow>
```

(Afraid i'm not on a machine with Android so i couldn't test the above code).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Emile! It works! You made my weekend! :)

I had to try it right away (althought it's friday evening), and here's what my xml now looks like:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shrinkColumns="0">  

<TableRow>
<!-- Column 1 -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/popupTitle"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/popupContent"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <!-- Column 2 -->
  <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:src="@drawable/img_30x30_px" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Please set my answer as the right answer so others can see your question has been answered. Thanks